# Function in MySQL script giving error : function_name does not exist

Tags: mysql

Here is a user defined function which takes a parameter clientID and finds the corresponding client in the table **trades** and checks if the date lies between a specific range of dates, then returns the trade id matching these conditions.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION insideTrade(clientID VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE tradeID VARCHAR(50);
    SELECT trade_id into tradeID 
    from trades
    join orders on trades.order_id = orders.order_id 
    where client_id = clientID and trade_time BETWEEN '1/2/2022 12:00' AND '1/4/2022 12:00'
    
    RETURN tradeID;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

When I run the function using below command, its showing an error that function name insideTrade does not exist

select insideTrade('CLT007') from trades

I can't seem to find an error with this code.

Comment: Are you sure the function got created? Did you select the database in which you created the function when you ran the select statement?

Comment: Function is syntactically incorrect - the select is not terminated - nb your ide would tell you that..